# Windows Display Manager slow down or error

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, display-driver

My computer is running pretty good, but I get the feeling that the Display Manager (or whatever it's called in windows) is having a hard time.

First, interaction with desktop items is slow and stuttering, meaning if for example I drag an icon around on the desktop, it looks like this is happening at 5 frames per second or so.

Second, when running a game or other maximized fullscreen applications on my main monitor while having other open windows on my other monitor, the windows display not their current content but some older stuff. I know this sounds weird, so let me explain using an image

[image]

This image shows what is displayed on my second monitor while running a game on the primary screen and having my chrome window on the second. Before this picture was taken, I've dragged my steam window over from the second to the first monitor and switched to a wikipedia tab in chrome before Alt-Tabbing back into the game.
Notice how only inside the chrome window there're remnants of the chrome window and the previous active tab in chrome, although you can see a tooltip of the wikipedia page being shown.

Both of these problem are already present right after system start and do not occur in safemode.

I've already completely removed and reinstalled my display and graphics drivers but this didn't solve the problem.

Does someone of you have any experience with this type of errors?

Here's some general information about my system:

- Win 7 Professional 64-bit SP1
- i5 3,40 GHz
- 8 GB ram
- ATI Radeon HD 7XXX Series
- AV & Firewall by Comodo

Comment: have you tried the 14.2 Beta driver? http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx

Comment: No but I'll try it next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing the intended behavior.  Starting with Vista, the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) draws the desktop and all windows on a Direct3D surface.  Full screen apps, like games, draw directly to the screen, bypassing DWM.

So when you switch to the game, DWM releases control of the screen while the window is being rendered and thus you see this behavior.  It is also great for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, that sheds some light on it. Could it be that deactivating Aero Themes caused this to start happening?

Comment: @Rickyfox: I assumed Aero was on.  If it is off, expect this to happen even if there is no fullscreen app as all apps draw directly to the screen.